# While creating an application using Microsoft Graph - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azureportal

I am trying to create an application in a directory using graph API but I am getting below error -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Error message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.6.0
SdkVersion : graph-java/v5.6.0
[...]

403 : Forbidden
[...]
```

This is the code that I using to create a Graph Service Client which I will use to call the Graph APIs...

```
private static GraphServiceClient<Request> createGraphClient() {
       
         
        ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .clientSecret(clientSecret)
                .tenantId(b2cDirectory)
                .build();

        TokenCredentialAuthProvider tokenCredentialAuthProvider = 
            new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(scopes, clientSecretCredential);
        
        GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
                .authenticationProvider(tokenCredentialAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();
        
        return graphClient;
    }
```

The graph client is successfully being created and now when I am trying to create the application using below code I am getting error which I shared above...

```
private static void createApplication(GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient) {
        
        System.out.println("Creating application...");
        
        Application application = new Application();
        application.displayName = "Test v3";
        application.publicClient = new PublicClientApplication();
        
        String appId = graphClient.applications()
                .buildRequest()
                .post(application)
                .appId;
        
        System.out.println("App ID: " + appId);
    }
```

I am very sure this has something with to do with giving permission to directory to allow graph to call and create Apps, but the portal.azure.com UI I am not able to find from where it is done...

Any suggestion please.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-app-registration#api-permissions---app-permissions-and-admin-consent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Azure AD B2C then select a random App from the list and then go to API permission...

[image]

Select the one I showed in screen shot and click on "Grant admin..." and try recalling the API.